# "cannot infer type for type f64" and "consider giving ... a type" error messages

Tags: rust, type-inference

This code works fine:

```rust
let list_of_integers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

let avg: f64 = f64::from(list_of_integers.iter().sum::<i32>()) / f64::from(list_of_integers.len() as i32);
```

But if I omit the turbofish for `sum()` I get this error message:

```
  |
4 |     let avg: f64 = f64::from(list_of_integers.iter().sum()) / f64::from(list_of_integers.len() as i32);
  |         ---        ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type `f64`
  |         |
  |         consider giving `avg` a type
  |
  = note: cannot resolve `f64: std::convert::From<_>`
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

What do those error messages mean? Did I somehow change the syntax and `: f64` isn't the type for `avg` anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `: f64` is still doing its job for `avg` - the problem here is that Rust doesn't know what the type of the argument to `f64::from` is. With the turbofish, it knows - it's an `i32`. Without, it doesn't - it could be any type for which the `std::iter::Sum<&i32>` trait is implemented. In the standard library, it just so happens that the only implementation of `std::iter::Sum<&i32>` returns an `i32`, but it's possible for other crates to implement the same trait with a different return type. So you need to tell rust what type it should be summing to.

The error message here is arguably pointing at the wrong function; it could either complain "I don't know what type this `sum()` will return" or "I don't know what type this `from` function will accept" - unfortunately it picked the less clear one in this case :)